# Ruby on Rails - Displaying Each Username in a Table

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-table, each

While making my ruby on rails application i've run into a little issue where in the repeating `<th>` tags I have to display one of each of the `User.username`'s while keeping the information in the `<td>` tags the same as displayed in the HTML below.

```
<% @rota.each do |rotum| %>  
  <h1>Week Commencing : <%= rotum.week %></h1>

<table class="rotum_table">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <% unless user.username == 'admin' %> 

  <tr><th><%= user.username %></th></tr>

  <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Sunday</th>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>USERNAME MUST GO HERE</th>
    <td><%= rotum.grid11 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid12 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid13 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid14 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid15 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid16 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid17 %></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <th>USERNAME MUST GO HERE</th>
    <td><%= rotum.grid21 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid22 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid23 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid24 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid25 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid26 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid27 %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>USERNAME MUST GO HERE</th>
    <td><%= rotum.grid31 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid32 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid33 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid34 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid35 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid36 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid37 %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>USERNAME MUST GO HERE</th>
    <td><%= rotum.grid41 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid42 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid43 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid44 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid45 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid46 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid47 %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>USERNAME MUST GO HERE</th>
    <td><%= rotum.grid51 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid52 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid53 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid54 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid55 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid56 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid57 %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>USERNAME MUST GO HERE</th>
    <td><%= rotum.grid61 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid62 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid63 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid64 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid65 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid66 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid67 %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>USERNAME MUST GO HERE</th>
    <td><%= rotum.grid71 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid72 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid73 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid74 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid75 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid76 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid77 %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>USERNAME MUST GO HERE</th>
    <td><%= rotum.grid81 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid82 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid83 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid84 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid85 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid86 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid87 %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>USERNAME MUST GO HERE</th>
    <td><%= rotum.grid91 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid92 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid93 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid94 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid95 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid96 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid97 %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>USERNAME MUST GO HERE</th>
    <td><%= rotum.grid101 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid102 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid103 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid104 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid105 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid106 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid107 %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th>USERNAME MUST GO HERE</th>
    <td><%= rotum.grid111 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid112 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid113 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid114 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid115 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid116 %></td>
    <td><%= rotum.grid117 %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<% end %>

<span class="approval_link">
<% @rota.each do |rotum| %>
  <%= link_to "Edit for Approval", new_approval_path(:id => rotum.id) %>
<% end %>
</span>

<% if current_user.admin %>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @rota.each do |rotum| %>
      <tr>

        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_rotum_path(rotum) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', rotum, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Rotum', new_rotum_path %>
<% end %>
```

So to reiterate, the `USERNAME MUST GO HERE` should change to for example, Corey, then Harry, then Michael. But where it says, for example,  `rotum.grid11`, `rotum.grid21` must stay the same. (In otherwords not be affected by the `@users.each do |user|`)

Comment: How are `users` connected with `rota` ?

Comment: `users` aren't actually connected with rota, it's just that that's where I need their usernames to be displayed.

Comment: but how to decide which user_name goes in which row ?